# Error page from chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I always get an error page when going to chat.meta.stackoverflow.com

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/

gets redirected to:

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/

Any idea what the problem is?

Browser: Firefox 3.6.6 on Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your domain cookies, visit meta, log in, then try again.

Comment: You really ought to fix that problem on your end instead of asking all of your users to clear their cookies.

Comment: @weblog there are some rare legacy cookies out there which we're about to stop supporting. (expire date in 4 months)

Comment: That worked - thanks. I guess I had one of those rare legacy cookies then.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on mobile? I'm seeing an odd error in the log about a mobile client...